# MYSQL Update from a select subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, substr, subquery

The data in the Response column is = `blahblahblahTYPE=ERRORblahblah`. I then run the query below to just target the 'ERROR' string.

```
SELECT substr(Response, instr(Response, 'ERROR'), 5) 
  FROM table 
  WHERE id = 721451 
    AND Status = 'false' 
    AND Response LIKE '%<status>Unknown</status>%' 
    AND date >= curdate();
```

The query above returns: `ERROR`.

I basically want to update `ERROR` to `SUCCESS` without editing the rest of the data.

Would the query below work? Is there a better way to do this?

```
UPDATE table 
  SET Response = 'SUCCESS' 
  WHERE (
    SELECT substr(Response, instr(Response, 'ERROR'), 5) 
      FROM table 
      WHERE id = 721451 
        AND Status = 'false' 
        AND Response LIKE '%<status>Unknown</status>%' 
        AND date >= curdate()
  );
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: @ReggieB Thanks for formatting my question! This is the first question I've posted, and am still kinda new to this...

Comment: Where that suqbery="ERROR"

Comment: @darshan-patel deserves credit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table 
  SET Response = REPLACE(Response, 'ERROR', 'SUCCESS')
   WHERE id = 721451 
     AND Status = 'false' 
     AND Response LIKE '%<status>Unknown</status>%' 
     AND date >= curdate();
```

Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: This look like a better response than mine - so I've removed my answer